# hiding the values on the basis total cases

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function which gives stats for mrset and also want to add something like if the total_cases is less then or equal to 3 then replace all the column values with "--"

I was trying like below but its not working perfectly

```
library(expss)

fun1 <- function(data, varlist, Banner) {
  
  t1 <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("cross_cpct(data,mrset(",head(varlist,1),"%to%",tail(varlist,1),"),Banner)")))
  replace_less_than_3 <- function(variable) {
    total_cases <- valid_n(t1[[variable]])
    if (total_cases < 3) {
      t1[[variable]][, (variable) := "--"]
    }
  }
  lapply(names(t1)[-1], replace_less_than_3)
  
  return(t1)
}
example <- data.frame(org = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                      q1 = c("apple", "apple", NA, "apple", "apple", "apple", NA),
                      q2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "banana", "banana", "banana", NA),
                      q3 = c("orange", NA, "orange", "orange", NA, "orange", NA),
                      region = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"))

df <- example
banner <- list(df$region)

debugonce(fun1)
result <- fun1(df, c("q1", "q2", "q3"), banner)
```

the output should be look like

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | -- | -- | -- |
| banana | -- | -- | -- |
| orange | -- | -- | -- |
| #Total cases | 2 | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a logical vector identifying those columns with a total of less than or equal to 2 (`lte2`), then index to replace all the desired entries in that column with the desired replacement (here, "--").

To do this in general (outside your function):

```
x <- cross_cpct(example, mrset(q1 %to% q3), banner)

lte2 <- c(FALSE, x[x$row_labels == "#Total cases", -1] <= 2)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE

x[-nrow(x), lte2] <- "--"

# |              |  1 |  2 |  3 |
# | ------------ | -- | -- | -- |
# |        apple | -- | -- | -- |
# |       banana | -- | -- | -- |
# |       orange | -- | -- | -- |
# | #Total cases |  2 |  2 |  2 |
```

To add this to your function:

```
fun1 <- function(data, varlist, Banner) {
  t1 <- eval(rlang::parse_expr(paste0("cross_cpct(data,mrset(",head(varlist,1),"%to%",tail(varlist,1),"),banner)")))
  lte2_t1 <- c(FALSE, t1[t1$row_labels == "#Total cases", -1] <= 2)
  t1[-nrow(t1), lte2_t1] <- "--"
  t1
}

fun1(df, c("q1", "q2", "q3"), banner)

# |              |  1 |  2 |  3 |
# | ------------ | -- | -- | -- |
# |        apple | -- | -- | -- |
# |       banana | -- | -- | -- |
# |       orange | -- | -- | -- |
# | #Total cases |  2 |  2 |  2 |
```

If you test on extended sample data to include an additional "orange" entry, you can see it works when the total > 2:

```
example <- data.frame(org = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                      q1 = c("apple", "apple", NA, "apple", "apple", "apple", NA),
                      q2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "banana", "banana", "banana", NA),
                      q3 = c("orange", NA, "orange", "orange", NA, "orange", "orange"),
                      region = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"))

fun1(example, c("q1", "q2", "q3"), banner)

#   |              |  1 |     2 |  3 |
#   | ------------ | -- | ----- | -- |
#   |        apple | -- |  33.3 | -- |
#   |       banana | -- |  33.3 | -- |
#   |       orange | -- | 100.0 | -- |
#   | #Total cases |  2 |   3.0 |  2 |
```